# Programmatically create a cold front vector (weather)

Tags: php, javascript, python, mapserver

Does anyone know a way to programmatically create a cold/warm front vector given a list of vertices (note the vertices do not contain the little triangles or half circles; [-105W, 40.45N],etc...)?

I'm trying to drop a "Current Front Positions" overlay on a web mapping application.

I was hoping to use PHP, Python, Javascript or even a map server to accomplish this task, but wanted to see if there were any good suggestions of where to start.

Comment: "Where to start" is trying a few things before coming here.

Comment: *Where to start:* 2D geometry imaging algorithms.

Comment: What would you do with this?  Generate an image?  Output on a web page?  There isn't nearly enough information here to help you.

Comment: On a web mapping application ( like google maps ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python;

You would have to capture the image first, e.g. using the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). You could use its [ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm) module to draw lines and arcs on the image.

If you want to draw ([Bézier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)) curves, you would need to find a library that can handle those. E.g. [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/), with the [py-cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) bindings.